# How to call modal from javascript function which was called by modal submit?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal in which there are 2 buttons- 'yes' and 'no-reprint'. What I want to do is, when a person clicks on 'no-reprint', the modal should close, call a javascript function to do some action and before the javascript function closes, recall the same modal with same buttons and everything..

I am able to call the javascript function but the modal does not reappear as first time.

modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLabelPrint" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modalTextLabelPrint">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="resetFunction();">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="reprintLabel();">No, Reprint Label</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript function:

```
function reprintLabel(){
    labelPrintCount++;
    $('#printDiv').append(printDivMain);

    console.log('after calling jprint');
    $('#modalLabelPrint').modal("show"); // not working.. needs some fixing.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the data-dismiss tag in the modal. The modal stays and I am able to call the other action as well.

modified code:

```
 </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="resetFunction();">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onclick="reprintLabel();">No, Reprint Label</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```